# SweetAlert2でgooglemap apiを使用する方法

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<script>
    swal({
        html: <div id="hoge"></div>
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#hoge").css({
           "width": "500px",
            "height": "500px",
        });
    });
    let map;
    let marker;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('hoge'), {
            center: {
                lat: 100,
                lng: 20,
            },
            zoom: 10
        });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: {
                lat: 100,
                lng: 20,
           },
           map: map,
        });
    }
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ja&key=HOGEHOGE&callback=initMap"></script>
</script>
```

このようにコードを書くとscriptタグでエラーが出て実装できませんでした。
どうすればよいですか？

Comment: どのようなエラーが発生していますか？そちらを追記していただくことは可能ですか？

Comment: ごめんさい。もう自己解決しました。わざわざコメントしていただきありがとうございました

Comment: 無事に自己解決しました。お騒がせしました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、その解決法や手段を明確に記述してくださると同じ問題に直面した人が助かります。よければお願いいたします。